# Exclude multiple authors by ID - IF condition

Tags: php

I am using this function to check for author name but I am looking to modify it to exclude an array of certain author IDs. Not sure about the easiest way to do this.

```
  function custom_author_block_render() {
    
      $author = wpgb_get_the_author();
    
      if ( empty( $author ) || 'author name' === $author ) {
        return;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Where do the function `wpgb_get_the_author()` comes from? Not really sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Is the set of authors going to be hard-coded or read from configuration? For both the name and ID you could have an array of the values to exclude, and test if $author is `$excludedAuthors.in_array( $author )`